# Remove empty string in nested json object via AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have an nested json object in which I need to remove empty values and create new json which should contain only data objects.
json file:

```
myData = [{
    "id": 1,
    "values": [{
        "value": ""
    }]
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "values": [{
        "value": 213
    }]

}, {
    "id": 3,
    "values": [{
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "value": "abc"
    }]

},{
    "id": 4,
    "values": [{
        "value": ""
    }]
},{
    "id": 33,
    "values": [{
        "value": "d"
    }]
}];
```

Output should be:

```
myNewData = [{
    "id": 2,
    "values": [{
        "value": 213
    }]

}, {
    "id": 3,
    "values": [{
        "value": "abc"
    }]

},{
    "id": 33,
    "values": [{
        "value": "d"
    }]
}];
```

So far I have created this:

```
    angular.module('myapp',[])
    .controller('test',function($scope){
    $scope.myData = [{
        "id": 1,
        "values": [{
            "value": ""
        }]
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "values": [{
            "value": 213
        }]

    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "values": [{
            "value": ""
        }, {
            "value": ""
        }, {
            "value": "abc"
        }]

    },{
        "id": 4,
        "values": [{
            "value": ""
        }]
    },{
        "id": 33,
        "values": [{
            "value": "d"
        }]
    }];

})
.filter('filterData',function(){
    return function(data) {
        var dataToBePushed = [];
        data.forEach(function(resultData){
            if(resultData.values && resultData.values != "")
                dataToBePushed.push(resultData);
        });
        return dataToBePushed;
    }
});
```

Html:

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="test">
        <div ng-repeat="data in myData | filterData">
            Id:{{ data.id }}
            </br>
            Values: {{ data.values }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am not able to access and remove value inside values object. Right now i am simply showing the data using ng-repeat but i need to create a new json file for that.

Answer (score 2):

You work with the array in your AngularJS Controller doing [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Map all objects doing a filter to exclude the items with empty values `item.values.value`, and than a filter to get the array elements that have values with value:

```js
var myData = [{"id": 1,"values": [{ "value": ""}]}, {"id": 2,"values": [{"value": 213}]}, {"id": 3,"values": [{"value": ""}, {"value": ""}, {"value": "abc"}]}, {"id": 4,"values": [{"value": ""}]}, {"id": 33,"values": [{"value": "d"}]}],
    myDataFiltered = myData
      .map(function (item) {
        item.values = item.values.filter(function (itemValue) {
          return itemValue.value;
        });
        return item;
      })
      .filter(function (item) {
        return item.values.length;
      });

console.log(myDataFiltered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES6:

```
myDataFiltered = myData
    .map(item => {
        item.values = item.values.filter(itemValue => itemValue.value);
        return item;
    })
    .filter(item => item.values.length);
```

Comment: Your first filter on `myData` should be a `map`, as its not filtering. This would also mutate the original object.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a multiple for-loop.

```js
myData = [{
    "id": 1,
    "values": [{
        "value": ""
    }]
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "values": [{
        "value": 213
    }]

}, {
    "id": 3,
    "values": [{
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "value": "abc"
    }]

},{
    "id": 4,
    "values": [{
        "value": ""
    }]
},{
    "id": 33,
    "values": [{
        "value": "d"
    }]
}];

function clone(obj){ return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));}
var result = [];
for(var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++){
 var current = clone(myData[i]);
  for(var j = 0; j < current.values.length; j++){
    if(current.values[j].value == null || current.values[j].value == ""){
      current.values.splice(j, 1);
      j--;
    }
  }
  if(current.values.length > 0) result.push(current);
}
console.log(myData);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: When i run the code snippet it prints the desired result ?

Comment: I am not OP but look at your result for `id=3`

Comment: You know that i console.log both arrays ? The myData and the result ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete them completely, you can iterate over the array like this;

```
angular.forEach($scope.myData, function(data){
    for(var i=0; i < data.values.length; i++){
         if(data.values[i] !== ""){
              break;
         }
         delete data;
    }
});
```

The if statement checks all values in the array, and breaks if it's not equal to "", otherwise if all values are = "" it deletes the object.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This doesn't go deeper than one level though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var myData = [{"id": 1,"values": [{ "value": ""}]}, {"id": 2,"values": [{"value": 213}]}, {"id": 3,"values": [{"value": ""}, {"value": ""}, {"value": "abc"}]}, {"id": 4,"values": [{"value": ""}]}, {"id": 33,"values": [{"value": "d"}]}]

let result=[],p=[];
myData.filter(el => {    
     p=[]; 
     el.values.filter(k => {k.value != '' ? p.push({value : k.value}) : null}); 
     if(p.length) result.push({id : el.id, values : p})
})
    
console.log('result', result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive function to do the job.

This will only work if `myData` is an array and the value inside it or its children is a collection of object.

```
var myData = [{"id": 1, "values": [{"value": ""}] }, {"id": 2, "values": [{"value": 213 }] }, {"id": 3, "values": [{"value": ""}, {"value": ""}, {"value": "abc"}] },{"id": 4, "values": [{"value": ""}] },{"id": 6, "values": ""},{"id": 33, "values": [{"value": "d"}] }];

function removeEmptyValues (arr) {
    var res = false;

    /* Iterate the array */
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        /* Get the object reference in the array */
        var obj = arr[i];

        /* Iterate the object based on its key */
        for (var key in obj) {

            /* Ensure the object has the key or in the prototype chain */
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

                /* So, the object has the key. And we want to check if the object property has a value or not */
                if (!obj[key]) {

                    /*
                        If it has no value (null, undefined, or empty string) in the property, then remove the whole object,
                        And reduce `i` by 1, to do the re-checking
                    */
                    arr.splice(i--, 1);

                    /* Amd set whether the removal occurance by setting it to res (result), which we will use for the next recursive function */
                    res = true;

                    /* And get out from the loop */
                    break;
                }

                /* So, the object has a value. Let's check whether it's an array or not */
                if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {

                    /* Kay.. it's an array. Let's see if it has anything in it */
                    if (!obj[key].length) {

                        /* There's nothing in it !! Remove the whole object again */
                        arr.splice(i--, 1);

                        /* Amd set whether the removal occurance by setting it to res (result), which we will use for the next recursive function */
                        res = true;

                        /* Yes.. gets out of the loop */
                        break;
                    }

                    /*
                        Now this is where `res` is being used.
                        If there's something removed, we want to re-do the checking of the whole object
                    */
                    if ( removeEmptyValues(obj[key]) ) {

                        /* Something has been removed, re-do the checking */
                        i--;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return res;
}

removeEmptyValues (myData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to right way but need some more operation like this :

```js
 angular.module('myapp',[])
    .controller('test',function($scope){
    $scope.myData = [{
        "id": 1,
        "values": [{
            "value": ""
        }]
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "values": [{
            "value": 213
        }]

    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "values": [{
            "value": ""
        }, {
            "value": ""
        }, {
            "value": "abc"
        }]

    },{
        "id": 4,
        "values": [{
            "value": ""
        }]
    },{
        "id": 33,
        "values": [{
            "value": "d"
        }]
    }];

})
.filter('filterData',function($filter){
    return function(data) {
        var dataToBePushed = [];
        data.forEach(function(resultData){
          var newValues=resultData;
          var hasData=$filter('filter')(resultData.values,{value:'!'},true);
          if(resultData.values && resultData.values.length>0 && hasData.length>0){
              newValues.values=hasData;
                dataToBePushed.push(newValues);
              }
        });
      debugger;
        return dataToBePushed;
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="test">
        <div ng-repeat="data in myData | filterData:''">
            Id:{{ data.id }}
            </br>
            Values: {{ data.values }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```